# Hide HTML code when using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

This sounds like a stupid question but i can't figure it out for the life of me.

So say I am making a dialog box.

```
<div id="dialog" title="mytitle" >blhablahablah
</div>
```

How do I stop that from showing up on the page. I only want to access it when it is in the dialog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `style="display:none;"` to your `<div>` tag.

Another solution would be adding `#dialog { display: none; }` to your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do through jquery you can do this way

but whatever Thiefmaster mentioned is more effective..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dialog').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use isOpen function of ui-dialog and then if it is false  hide the element